# Is there a renaming tool (for Ubuntu 18.04 Mate) which is able to work on folder names as well?

Tags: directory, mate, rename

I am rather new to Linux, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Mate. When I need to do more complex file renaming tasks I prefer to use KRename (the GUI version that got installed with apt-get). But often I'd also like to rename **folders' names** (this question is NOT about batch renaming of **file** names). It seems KRename (GUI) is not capable of doing that. So I wonder whether there's a tool to achieve that (as a beginner I prefer not to write scripts).

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/batch-rename-files-in-linux/

Comment: Or `thunar -B`. See also https://ostechnix.com/how-to-rename-multiple-files-at-once-in-linux/

Comment: I'd use a terminal and just use `mv` (usually easier than `rename` but I may use that too for some).  You've not given many details; ie. what OS, release & desktop you're using; mention of `krename` makes me think of KDE so where you have multiple GUI choices as well - but you've not said why those aren't usable to you (ie. `dolphin` etc).

Comment: @guiverc: I edited the question to give more details. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Mate. I'm a beginner, it's easier for me and faster to use a GUI than to write a script or use the command line when I have to rename dozens of files (and folders). As a beginner I also have limited knowledge of alternatives, I do not even know whether there are different GUIs to KRename.

Comment: "I have to rename dozens of files (and folders)" ... that is called "batch renaming"

Comment: @muru: the question is not about **files**, it's about **folders**. That's the point.

Comment: @Shakesbeer For renaming, there's no difference. *That's*  the point.

Comment: @muru: That may be true for the command line but not for KRename GUI: when I add a folder, how can I get it to process the folder's name instead of adding the folder's content (the names of the files in it) to the list of objects to rename?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file  (a basic theory from 1970 in unix, that applies in modern day GNU/Linux just as it did back then)   Also note Ubuntu-MATE being a *flavor* of Ubuntu, came with 3 years of life, which ended April-2021; see https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966

Comment: @guiverc: I didn't ask for a theoretical introduction to the way that information is organized on a file system or whatever. As long as - in this case - KRename GUI does not treat files and folders identically, there IS a difference. And that difference leads to my question.

Comment: You can use `caja` which comes with Ubuntu-MATE, and will use less resources (as it shares libraries/toolkits with your desktop unlike `krename`).  If you're online, don't forget to use `ubuntu-support-status` to decide for yourself the risks of using a EOL OS (parts of your system in common with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS are still supported; MATE, `krunner` etc are not)

Comment: @Shakesbeer https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/72944-Krename-Renaming-Folders?p=409594&viewfull=1#post409594?

Comment: Did you find anything of what was posted useful? It is always good to provide feedback.

Comment: I will do some tests and report the results as soon as I find the time, please be patient.

Comment: ... any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few options, both via command line or GUI.
Which one suits your needs *may* depend on the patterns you want to use for renaming.

I am only citing explicitly here one GUI option (since you used KRename), which is `thunar -B`

[image]

You could check other alternatives in sources below.

if using CLI, you could always "wrap" your command with `for d in $(find . -type d <other options>) ; do <your operations on "${d}", including renaming> ; done`.

**Sources**:

1. https://www.makeuseof.com/batch-rename-files-in-linux/
2. https://ostechnix.com/how-to-rename-multiple-files-at-once-in-linux/

Comment: Using a `for` loop like you suggested is discouraged. Rather `-exec` option to `find` should be used: `find . -type d <other options> -exec <your operations on {}> \;`

Comment: @raj - I actually use a lot your suggestion. But what is posted works fine in many cases.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/2707864 provides further info.
If you could add the reasons why/the cases when `for ... $(find ...)` is discouraged, that will help a lot.

Comment: It will cause trouble when directory names contain spaces or other characters that could be interpreted as separators by `for`.

Answer (score 0):

### `rename` can rename both files and directories

A command line tool is suitable for this kind of task. I can show how it works with an example:

Make two test directories

```
$ mkdir rentest1
$ mkdir rentest2
```

Make a test file

```
$ touch rentest3
```

Check that `rename` does what you expect with a 'dry run' using the option `-n`

```
$ rename -n 's/ren/rename-/' rentest*
rename(rentest1, rename-test1)
rename(rentest2, rename-test2)
rename(rentest3, rename-test3)
```

When it looks good, remove `-n` and do it

```
$ rename 's/ren/rename-/' rentest*
```

Check that it worked for both the file and the directories

```
$ ls -ld rename*
drwxrwxr-x 2 sudodus sudodus 4096 aug 11 13:47 rename-test1
drwxrwxr-x 2 sudodus sudodus 4096 aug 11 13:47 rename-test2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sudodus sudodus    0 aug 11 13:48 rename-test3
```

Learn about all the features in

```
man rename
```

My version of rename is installed via the package `rename` from the repository `universe`, and it is a Perl script by Larry Wall.